# SQLite3 fetch multiple columns in one SELECT statement (python)

Tags: python, sqlite, fetch

I am wondering how to fetch more than 1 column at the same time. This is the code I have so far but iI get the error:
`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

```
con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT name, age FROM employees")
name, age = cur.fetchall()
```

Is it actually possible to fetch more than 1 column at the same time?
Thanks!

Comment: `fetachall` returns a list of each row as tuples, it doesn't return a tuple hence the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cur.fetchall()` gives you a list of `(name, age)` tuples, as many as there are rows in your `employees` table. Your contains more than just two rows, so your `name, age = ...` syntax fails because that requires there to be two results. Even if there *are* only two rows, you'd assign those two rows (each a tuple) to the names `name` and `age` which is probably not what you wanted.

You probably want to *iterate over the cursor*; this lets you process each row tuple separately, including assigning the two column values to two separate targets:

```
for name, age in cur:
    # process each name and age separately
```

or just assign the `cur.fetchall()` result to a single variable:

```
results = cur.fetchall()
```

and process the list as needed.